# intellij idea macro grayed out

Tags: intellij-idea

I've just recorded a macro in IntelliJ Idea basically to record me typing

```
<div class="blah></div>
```

Then I clicked 'Stop recording', then named the macro. I see my named macro under Tools, but it is grayed out even though my cursor is on a HTML file. Anyone know why I can't use the macro?

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to use **Live Templates** for such tasks. As for the problem with Macro, we'll need more details like the sample project, IDEA version, your OS.

Answer (score 0):

As CrazyCoder said use a template. For example:

```
<div class="$CLASS$">$END$</div>
```

Then <kbd>Edit variables</kbd> set `CLASS` expression to `"blah"` (including the double quotes).

Set abbrevation to div, and applicable contexts to html.

Then just type `div` <kbd>Tab</kbd> in an html file, edit the class name and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to end up between div tags.